# Validation rule text in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

In MS Access I have a table with two fields: ID (Autonumber) and SerialNumber (Text).
Serial Number should contains only unique values, therefore I set up it Indexed: Yes (No Duplicates).
Now when I try to enter two same values into SerialNumber field it shows me some standard error message. I need to show custom own message to user like: "Serial Number should be unique!".
I added that message to "Validation Text" but it doesn't help, it still shows standard Access error message. Does anyone know how to show custom error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Index constraint overrides the validation rule.

You may be able to get away with a validation rule using DLookup - but I'd strongly advise against it as it will seriously impact your database performance.

A better option is to trap for the error using VBA and then issue your own custom error message.

You can also customize the error message that is returned if you are using MS-SQL as your database backend (which it doesn't sound like you are).

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  Select Case DataErr
    Case 3022 ' Duplicate Value Detected
      MsgBox "That Serial Number already Exists.", vbOkayOnly
      Response = acDataErrContinue
  End Select
End Sub
```

This traps all errors on the form, and looks to see if the error is a duplicate value.  If it is, a message box is displayed to the user advising the serial number already exists - it then proceeds normally.